# Métodos de clases en pygame

Tags: pygame

Este pequeño programa que estoy haciendo para interiorizarme un poco más en Pygame consiste en varias pelotas de distintos tamaños que rebotan contra las pared. Utilicé Clases para hacer esto como pueden observar y la llamada a los métodos de esta clase se pueden ver en el bucle while que se encarga de inicializar la ventana de pygame.

Cuando lo ejecuto, la propiedad bounce(rebotar) sólo se aplica a algunos de los objetos creados (entre 1 y 3). El resto simplemente sale de la pantalla sin rebotar o haciéndolo sólo algunas veces.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 500
canvas = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(width/2, height/2)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(1, 4), random.randint(-4, 4))
        self.radio = random.randint(3, 8)
        self.color = (150, 0, 150)

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(canvas, self.color, (int(self.position.x), int(self.position.y)), self.radio*2)

    def move(self):
        self.position.x += self.velocity.x
        self.position.y += self.velocity.y

    def bounce(self):
            
        if self.position.x == 0 + self.radio:
            self.velocity.x *= -1
        elif self.position.x == width - self.radio:
            self.velocity.x *= -1
        elif self.position.y == 0 + self.radio:
            self.velocity.y *= -1
        elif self.position.y == height - self.radio:
            self.velocity.y *= -1
    
run = True
Balls = []
cantidad = 10

for i in range(cantidad):
    i = Ball()
    Balls.append(i)

while run:

    pygame.time.delay(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #Esto te permite usar la X pa salir del programa
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    canvas.fill(0) # Si no redibujas el fondo, se llenará de un monton de circulos
    
    for b in Balls:
        b.render()  
        b.move()    
        b.bounce()  
        
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es en las condicionales que limitan la zona de trabajo. Es que a veces no se llega al valor exacto y por lo mismo en lugar de regresarse se sale de la pantalla. Te propongo la siguiente funcion bounce. En lugar de usar igualdades utiliza desigualdades por si no se llega al valor exacto que deseas validar.

```
  def bounce(self):
            
        if self.position.x <= 0 + self.radio:
            self.velocity.x *= -1
        elif self.position.x >= width - self.radio:
            self.velocity.x *= -1
        elif self.position.y <= 0 + self.radio:
            self.velocity.y *= -1
        elif self.position.y >= height - self.radio:
            self.velocity.y *= -1
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, eso me ayudo.

Saludos.